# NSOutlineView expand / collapse animation from code

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsoutlineview

i'm wondering how does one **animate** the expansion/collapse of an NSOutlineView's tree node **from code** ?

```
// this works ok but doesn't animate  

NSTreeNode *node = [self.outlineView itemAtRow:self.outlineView.clickedRow];

if([self.outlineView isItemExpanded:node])
{
    [self.outlineView.animator collapseItem:node];
}else{
    [self.outlineView.animator expandItem:node];
}
```

an outline view naturally animates if you expand a node via the default-drawn arrow
so there IS a way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My original code was OK, this just wasn't available under 10.7

Original text from [Application Kit Release Notes for OS X v10.8](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html) :

NSOutlineView

The following methods now support being animated via the -animator proxy: -expandItem:, -expandItem:expandChildren:, -collapseItem:, and -collapseItem:collapseChildren:. As an example, to animate the expansion of a particular item: [[outlineView animator] expandItem:item];

Comment: Can you link to the release notes where it says that?

Comment: Done. Said text is in the NSOutlineView section

Comment: If you're using Swift, you won't get autocompletion in Xcode when you are trying to type `outlineView.animator().ex`. Maybe it's a bug. But it actually works if you type it manually `outlineView.animator().expandItem(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the `node` you are passing to `collapseItem:`.  You need to pass the object your tree controller uses to represent the node rather than the actual node from your data model.  If you are using NSTreeController, then you need to traverse the structure returned from `-[NSTreeController arrangedObjects]` to locate the node that represents your data model object.

Comment: hi there, i had suceeded in opening/collapsing via code  
what i have a problem with is ANIMATING it