# NSOutlineView Expand / Collapse item with animation from code

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have an outline view where I need to expand / collapse items when clicked anywhere on the row and I am being successful in doing that except the animation behavior is not same as when disclosure triangle is clicked to expand / collapse.

```
public override bool ShouldSelectItem(NSOutlineView outlineView, NSObject item)
{
    if (outlineView.IsItemExpanded(item)) 
    {
       outlineView.CollapseItem(item, false);
    }
    else
    {
       outlineView.ExpandItem(item, false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone help me write the missing code to achieve desired animation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the animator? See [NSOutlineView expand / collapse animation from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881034/nsoutlineview-expand-collapse-animation-from-code).

Comment: @Willeke no relative syntax available in xamarin.mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NSOutlineView's Animator proxy:

Get a reference to the `Animator`, cast it as an `NSOutlineView` and then call the method that you want to have the "default" animation applied.

Example:

```
 (MyOutline.Animator as NSOutlineView).ExpandItem(MyOutline.GetChild(0, null), true);
```